# Python: Time input validation

Tags: python, python-2.7, date

I have the fallowing problem, 
Im supposed to get user input in the form of `10:10:10` (hh:mm:ss) or `10:10`(mm:ss) or `10`(ss). Now i need check the fallowing parameters:

- If I'm getting only seconds then there is no limit.
- If I'm getting `mm:ss` then the seconds are limited to 0..59 and minutes are unlimited.
- If I'm getting `hh:mm:ss` then both seconds and minutes are limited to 0..59 while hours are unlimited.

Then return a TimeDelta object.

The naive way is to write multiply `if` statements to check all this. 
But im looking for a smoother way.

```
val = "11:66:11"
try:
    val = map(int, val.split(':'))
except ValueError:
    return False
if len(val) == 1:
    return val
if len(val) == 2:
    if val[1] > 59:
        print  "Bad seconds"
        return False
if len(val) == 3:
    if val[2] > 59 or val[1] >59:
        print  "Bad seconds / minutes"
        return False
while len(val) < 3:
        split.insert(0,0)
return = timedelta(hours=split[0],minutes=split[1],seconds=split[2])
```

Comment: Have you got any error? What problem u are facing ?

Comment: No errors, the code i wrote is the native way to do what i want. Im asking for a more smoother way. A more pythonic way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using regular expression here:

```
import re
import datetime
pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d+)(?::([0-5]?\d)(?::([0-5]?\d))?)?$')

def str2seconds(val):
    match = pattern.match(val)
    if not match:
        raise ValueError("Invalid input: %s" % val)
    else:
        result = 0
        for i in match.groups():
            if i is not None:
                result *= 60
                result += int(i)

    return datetime.timedelta(seconds=result)
```

Example:

```
>>> print(str2seconds('255'))
0:04:15
>>> print(str2seconds('255:25'))
4:15:25
>>> print(str2seconds('255:25:25'))
10 days, 15:25:25
>>> print(str2seconds('255:25:25:255'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "y.py", line 8, in str2seconds
    raise ValueError("Invalid input: %s" % val)
ValueError: Invalid input: 255:25:25:255
>>> print(str2seconds('255:25:60'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "y.py", line 8, in str2seconds
    raise ValueError("Invalid input: %s" % val)
ValueError: Invalid input: 255:25:60
```

---

The regular expression part by part:

- `^`: beginning of string
- `(\d+)`: 1-n digits, captured as group 1
- `(?::([0-5]?\d)(?::([0-5]?\d))?)?` optional part:

  - `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group
  - `:` matches literal `:`
  - `([0-5]?\d)` an optional digit 0-5, followed by a digit, captured as group 2
  - there is a second non-capturing group in the first:
    `(?::([0-5]?\d))?` that optionally matches second `:` followed by
    an optional digit 0-5 followed by a digit; and capturing the digits into group 3
  - and finally `$` matches the end of the string. Strictly, `^` at the beginning is not necessary as `match` anchors the match at the beginning; however the `$` is necessary, as otherwise the match is not anchored at the end of the string! (Python 3.4 added [the `re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) to fix this.)

The `match.groups()` will be a tuple of 3 items; the non-matching groups will be returned as `None`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Can you please exlain the regex? Tried to understand it but got kinda stuck.

Comment: If you try to solve a problem using regexs, very often you end up having two problems. I think a more basic string analysis is more appropriate.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What joke? If the OP has to change that regexp, he will have a hard time. Using however a more standard (verbose, if you may) approach, he or anybody else will be able to change it now or in three years.

Comment: Simple regexp is simple. True that the regexp could be written in verbose mode with some comments -- which is what you'd do with "standard verbose approach" anyway, if maintainability is a priority.